# Basic set theory - discrete mathematics

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics

Please help me with this question! I've always thought that if $xy = z$, then $x$ or $y$ must be a factor of $z$ and so doesn't that mean all values of $n$ are possible where at least one of the numbers is a factor? But the nature of the question suggests there must be some sort of logic that determines specific cases where $p(n)$ is true...

given $p(n)$:

$∀x∀y(xy ∈ nN) \Rightarrow (x \in nN ∨ y ∈ nN).$

For which values of $n$, where $2≤n≤7$, is $p(n)$ true? Justify your answer.

More generally, for which values of $n\in N$ do you think $p(n)$ is true? You do not need to justify your answer.

Comment: As I'm understanding, consider if $n=6$.  then $nN = 6N = \{6,12,18,24,\cdots\}$.  Letting $x=3$ and $y=2$, you have $xy=6\in 6N$, however neither $x$ nor $y$ are in $6N$.  Consider what is special about the number 6 compared to another number like 5 that allowed this discrepancy to happen.

Comment: OOOOHHHHH!!! Thank you very much! (I'm new to maths haha) I didn't understand the question but now that you put it that way...So the thing here is that 3 and 2 can't be multiples of 6 because they're smaller than 6. So the number 4 also wouldn't work because
let x=2 and y=2, we have xy = 4 ∈4N
However, neither 2 or 2 are a multiple of 4.
So, I guess the values p(n) are true when...they aren't the product of numbers that are smaller than them and are prime?

Comment: You're getting closer.  More generally however, you'll see that the statement you've labeled as $p(n)$ is true if and only if n is prime.  If n happens to be composite (in other words a multiple of two numbers neither of which are 1), then you can have this situation.  Take $p(16)$ for example with $x=4$ and $y=4$.  In this case, neither $x$ nor $y$ are prime, but it still is untrue.

Comment: Ah prime numbers work because they're the only ones where one of the factors has to be n itself to make p(n) true.
 
Could you explain the point you make in "neither x nor y are prime, but it still is untrue". Does that suggest that if either x or y isn't prime, there is some difference? Or do you just mean that n must be prime and x or y being prime or not doesn't matter? Sorry, I don't understand what you're trying to explain in that last part...

Would totally +rep you but don't know how!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

continuing the conversation from above, I was showing a counter example to your earlier statement that

> "So, I guess the values p(n) are true when...they aren't the product of numbers that are >smaller than them and are prime?"

which I interpreted as you thinking perhaps that the numbers x and y needed to be prime, which is untrue.  If you had intended that to be that the number n needed to be prime, then yes you are correct.  As for +rep, there is an arrow to the left of the post (either in comments or in answers).

---

To summarize what went on in the above conversation, the statement is true iff $n$ is prime, for if $n$ were not prime, you could pick $x$ and $y$ such that neither $x$ nor $y$ are equal to $n$ and $xy = n$.  As a result, $xy\in nN$ but $x\notin nN = \{n, 2n, 3n, 4n, \cdots\}$ since $x<n$ (and similarly for $y$)

Comment: That makes perfect sense. Thank you so very much! You've helped someone who hasn't done this subject before and hasn't touched maths in 3 years to understand completely! Thank you!